# Replace resize with cv2.INTER_AREA with equivalent blur or something else

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I want to replace image resize: `im_out = cv2.resize(im_in, (w // 2, h // 2), cv2.INTER_AREA)` with some operation: `im_blur = cv2.smth(im_in, *args)`

More accurately, I want to obtain such `im_blur` that `im_out == im_blur[::2, ::2]` or `im_out == im_blur[1::2, 1::2]`, so corresponding pixel values should be same, but other pixels should have some logical continuation.

To the best of my knowledge, im_blur can be obtained with `cv2.blur` with kernel size 2, because cv2.INTER_AREA is just a averaging over neighbor pixels. But when I do following only around 30% percent of pixels satisfy condition above.

Maybe I don't understand exactly how resize with `cv2.INTER_AREA` works and maybe youcan help me understand this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is your input image's size a multiple of two, or not? in general, do not expect PERFECTLY IDENTICAL results. that is rarely a requirement. please state the absolute differences between pixels you see. how many have 0 difference, how many have difference of 0, difference of 2, ...

Comment: I think you will have to set filter anchor to (0,0) and make sure that there is effectively no border applied. I remember to have answered once a question about even-sized filters, but maybe it was about morphological operations. I'll take a look.

Comment: I found that problem exists in odd heights and width, for even cv2.blur with kernel size 2 works fine.
So maybe this happens because of border during resize.

Comment: in C++ I'm observing rounding errors leading to a difference between resize INTER_AREA and blur+subsampling of up to 1 intensity per channel (8 bit accuracy). But interestingly, if the input image consists only of horizontal or vertical lines of random color, there are no differences at all. might INTER_AREA or blur be averaging in some optimized way like first averaging all the rows or all the lines in the filter-area?

Comment: for diagonal lines the difference will again be up to 1 intensity per channel. And for all tests (except diagonal): If I set the kernel anchor to (-1,-1) differences are bigger, So anchor is important.

Comment: testing with 32 bit floating point precision images, difference is 0 in all tests, when kernel-anchor = (0,0)

Comment: Thank you, anchor == (0, 0) significantly reduce difference